# Why isn't a C++11 acquire_release fence enough for Dekker synchronization?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, synchronization, atomic, memory-fences

The failure of Dekker-style synchronization is typically explained with reordering of instructions.  I.e., if we write

```
atomic_int X;
atomic_int Y;
int r1, r2;
static void t1() { 
    X.store(1, std::memory_order_relaxed)
    r1 = Y.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
}
static void t2() {
    Y.store(1, std::memory_order_relaxed)
    r2 = X.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
}
```

Then the loads can be reordered with the stores, leading to `r1==r2==0`.

I was expecting an acquire_release fence to prevent this kind of reordering:

```
static void t1() {
    X.store(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acq_rel);
    r1 = Y.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
}
static void t2() {
    Y.store(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acq_rel);
    r2 = X.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
}
```

The load cannot be moved above the fence and the store cannot be moved below the fence, and so the bad result should be prevented.

However, experiments show `r1==r2==0` can still occur.  Is there a reordering-based explanation for this?  Where's the flaw in my reasoning?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As I understand it (mainly from reading [Jeff Preshings blog](http://preshing.com/20130922/acquire-and-release-fences/)), an `atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acq_rel)` prevents any reorderings except for `StoreLoad`, i.e., it still allows to reorder a `Store` with a subsequent `Load`. However, this is exactly the reordering that has to be prevented in your example.

More precisely, an `atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire)` prevents the reordering of any previous `Load` with any subsequent `Store` and any subsequent `Load`, i.e., it prevents `LoadLoad` and `LoadStore` reorderings across the fence.

An `atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release)` prevents the reordering of any subsequent `Store` with any preceding `Store` and any preceding `Load`, i.e., it prevents `LoadStore` and `StoreStore` reorderings across the fence.

An `atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acq_rel)` then prevents the union, i.e., it prevents `LoadLoad`, `LoadStore`, and `StoreStore`, which means that only `StoreLoad` may still happen.

Answer (score 5):

`memory_order_acq_rel` actually behaves just as acquire and release fence at the same place. But the issue is that they do not prevent all the possible reordering, they prevent consequent loads or prior stores from being reordered around the fence. So, prior loads and consequent stores can still pass through the fence.

In Dekker synchronization, it is important to prevent e.g. the load from being reordered before the store in *another* thread, i.e. before the fence.
Now, unroll your loops where this synchronization occurs and you'll get that the load from previous iteration can fall through the fence on the current iteration.

`memory_order_seq_cst` works fine for Dekker's synchronization because it prevents any reordering across this point. For example, [tbb](/questions/tagged/tbb) uses it Dekker's algorithm and `mfence` for the work-stealing.

For better understanding, see great animation from Herb Sutter lecture "[Atomic<> weapons 1/2](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-atomic-Weapons-1-of-2)", at 0:43.